# Cannot update useState of array type inside if condition in an event based function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am a beginner, currently into both javascript and react. I have been trying to implement multiple checkboxes where every time a checkbox is checked the name is added to a useState variable - an array.

```
const [members, setMembers] = useState([])
let selectedMembers = []
const handleCheck = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked){
        selectedMembers.includes(e.target.name) === false && selectedMembers.push(e.target.name)
        console.log(selectedMembers,"one")
    }else if(e.target.checked === false){
        const sm = selectedMembers.filter((itm)=>itm !== e.target.value )
        selectedMembers = sm
    }
    // here we have the array of all the names selected which is updated every time it is selected
    console.log(selectedMembers)

    //but when I add this line here, it only shows the last element in the array everytime it is checked
    setMembers(selectedMembers)
    console.log(members)
}


   //My html code is soemthing like this for all checkboxes

   <input type="checkbox" name="Sima Rana"  id="edit-two" onChange={(e)=>handleCheck(e)}/>}
   <label htmlFor="edit-two" className="wp d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
```

The problem is, that I cannot have the useState add elements to the state array. I have had this kind of issue previously, couldn't find a solution, and chose another way to do it every time. But now I really need to understand what's going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that auxiliary variable `selectedMembers` it should be causing your problems.

Try to change all your logic to use the state.

```
const [members, setMembers] = useState([])
const handleCheck = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked && members.includes(e.target.name) === false){
        setMembers([
          ...members,
          e.target.name,
        ])
    } else if(e.target.checked === false){
        setMembers(member.filter((itm)=>itm !== e.target.value))
    }
}
```

Something like this